# Reaching the Max Limit for Ids in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-design, scalability

In mySQL, I used primary key as UINT32. The ID will soon reach its limit of 4,294,967,295. My service is a node application.

What is the solution to handle this situation efficiently?

I use schemapack.js for object serialisation in my node application. Can't use BIGINT or UINT64 because schemapack doesn't support the datatype.

This table is not used in historical context. Only realtime services use this table.

https://github.com/phretaddin/schemapack#here-is-a-table-of-the-available-data-types-for-use-in-your-schemas

Approaches I can think of:

1. Create a new table when the ID approaches 1% of the max limit. The problem with this approach is all other services must be notified efficiently of the change in table name. It can cause multiple race conditions and a lot of failures. There are multiple clusters running the node application.
2. Since this table is not used in historical context, old data can be overwritten with new data. Reset ID to 0 once the limit is reached and overwrite old records.
3. Once the limit is reached, delete a segment of the table. Divide the table into segments and use Queue approach to remove segments (First in- first out) every time the limit is reached.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? [ask] [Help] [mre] What does that link have to do with whatever you are trying to ask? Put everything needed to ask in your post, not at a link. Show what parts you are able to do. "efficiently" means nothing  in particular. What exactly to you mean? Where are you stuck determining it? Please don't dump specifications and/or wonderings.

Comment: Are there really 4 billion rows?  Or have lots of them been deleted over time?

Comment: If you are using `AUTO_INCREMENT`, "resetting to zero" simply won't work (unless you remove all the data first).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite subjective to say what the best approach for your situation is. It's about weighing up the pros and cons of different solutions for *your* application/setup.

I am not familiar with schemapack, but I guess the 32-bit integer limitation stems from the fact JS doesn't natively support 64-bit integers (although `BigInt` is on the way to address that problem). The traditional `Number` JS type can be used for integers of up to 53 bits w/o sacrificing precision, but that's not exactly 64 bits.

If you need to support 64-bit integers in JS, you can use the string type. It would definitely be slower, but for your particular case that might not be noticeable/significant. Integers encoded as strings/varchars could take a little bit more space (you can consider encoding those integers in HEX, which would be slightly more space-efficient than a standard decimal representation, but at the same time relatively convenient). That approach is also a bit more error-prone. Overall, if you can't or don't want to use `BigInt`s, strings might be a reasonable workaround if you need to work with bigger numbers.